# email validation arguments - Wrong number of args in test Michael Hartl Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Followed the instructions in chapter 6, tutorial test should be GREEN(no failures/errors), but I'm receiving the below error
Expecting the test results to pass. From the error, I understand there's a missing an arg, but unsure what to change

## user_test.rb

```
test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
  valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org 
  first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
  valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
    @user.email = valid_address
    assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
  end
end

test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
  invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
  invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
    @user.email = invalid_address
    assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
  end
end

#user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
end
```

> ERROR["test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses", UserTest, 0.41518251600001577]
>    test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses#UserTest (0.42s)
>   ArgumentError:         ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
>              test/models/user_test.rb:41:in `test'
>              test/models/user_test.rb:41:in`block in '

Comment: As the error says, the failing test is called "test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses", which is not the one that you posted in your question. Can you show us the test with that name?

Comment: This has now been added

Answer (score 0):

I have now managed to get this working. Appears the indentation on the tests was causing AWS cloud9 to throw an error asking for an expected keyword_end. I believe adding an extra end was creating the above error message. Solution: indented code correctly using the keyword_end in the correct places fixed my problem.